# How do I generate unique binary codes, for a specific alphabet, that never overlaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary, huffman-code

So, I'm trying to solve a challenge regarding decoding some huffman compressed message, without knowing the code tree used to compress with.

I do however know the alphabet that was used in the message.
So my idea was to try to bruteforce it but I am a bit lacking in my algoritm skills.

I imagined I would try to generate the codes for the letters, in all possible combinations.
The issue is though, that the codes (in binary) can never be able to hide eachother.

So an example could be:

| Letter | Code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0100 |
| B | 1111 |
| C | 1011 |

But then there couldn't be any other codes, that start with any of the above, as they would end up hiding eachother.

So, for a 40 character alphabet, I would like create unique, non-hiding bit codes.
I have no idea where to start though. Any tips are appreciated.

- Are there any smart algoritms I'm not aware of (very likely)?
- Is it called something I don't know, which could help me search?
- Any tips on how to actually create this, in any way?

Comment: Not to answer your question, but the term you're looking for is a "prefix code", a coding in which no coding is a prefix of another.

Comment: Huffman coding is not reversible without additional information. For example, with a 3 character alphabet there's only one valid Huffman tree: { 0, 10, 11 } but there are six ways to assign the characters to the codes. With a 40 character alphabet, there are roughly 2 billion valid trees, and 40! (that's 40 factorial) ways the characters can be assigned.

Comment: Do you know the message, and then you are asked to come up with the code? There is no way to find the message with the just alphabet and the message bits. There is a ginormous number of possible valid solutions.

Comment: Yea, I realize it's a lot of combinations and perhaps not possible in the end. It is however just a for-fun challenge between some coworkers. No stakes, no deadlines. Just wanted to give the bruteforce approach a shot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to just enumerate through all possible encodings.  I can easily come up with a scheme to generate over 2^39 different encodings, and each of those encodings will have 40! different ways of assigning codes to letters.

Let `x` be a random 40-bit string.  Look at

```
~x[0]
x[0:1] + ~x[1]
x[0:2] + ~x[2]
x[0:3] + ~x[3]
....
x[0:39] + ~x[39]
x[0:40]
```

This is a prefix code for any value `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Binary numbers map one-to-one with decimal numbers, so you can cover a two-character alphabet with binary numbers of length 1, four-characters with length 2, etc.

So for a 40-character alphabet you'll need binary codes of length 6. Then if you have them in a list:

```
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...]
```

You could get your mapping with

```
mapping = {alphabet[i]: format(i, "b").zfill(6) for i in range(len(alphabet))}

{'A': '000000', 'B': '000001', 'C': '000010', ...}
```

Comment: I don't think this generates a prefix code like Huffman coding.

Comment: Yea, it's not the actual binary code of the letter that I need. It is instead a unique code, of variable length. Basically it's a compression algorithm that I'm trying to brute-force reverse. So the codes are a way to make each byte take up less bits, which is why they are generated this way instead of just being their actual binary value.